# How to covnert int64 data into ?day, month and year?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date feature in the format 20001130 and another 2000-11-30 without any space. How can i write the optimized code that works for both to split the date into day month and year efficiently

Comment: If they're in a Pandas dataframe, high chance that `20001130` is a string. That said, if this is a Pandas question, you should provide some sample data(frame).

Comment: It is a dataframe 20001130  is int and 2000-11-30  is date type. which is quite irritating

Comment: I can wrtie a function and use apply but for that i need to change 20001130 to 2000-11-30  so that i can split it to date month and year. But i am looking for something more optimized

Comment: are the two in the same column? you can try: `pd.to_datetime(df['col'].astype(str))`.

Comment: this isn't just an int, this is string formatting of a date. convert to string (if it isn't already) and search for parsing dates in python. also, first try to solve yourself before asking.

Comment: nope both are in different columns one with 20001130 and another column with 2000-11-30

Comment: I have attempted in solving it already i want to see if an optimized solution that exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pandas.to_datetime`:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime([20001130, 20001129], format='%Y%m%d')
```

or with a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [20001129, 20001130]})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%Y%m%d')
```

**EDIT**
The two date formats should be in one column. In this case, convert all to strings and let `pandas.to_datetime` interpret the values, as it supports different formats in one column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [20001129, '2000-11-30']})
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time.astype(str))
```

|  | time |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2000-11-29 |
| 1 | 2000-11-30 |

Comment: This works to convert 20001129 to 2000-11-29 but what i want to do is to convert both 20001129 and 2000-11-29  to split directly to date month and year. Is it possible to convert it at one shot without first having hypens aded?

Comment: Don't answer questions where OP hasn't attempted to solve.

Comment: @Mohammed Nadeem: what exactly do you want archive. Can you provide a min. DataFrame with the entries you expect?

Comment: No worries i was able to solve it. basically i wanted to convert 20001130 and 2000-11-30 into day , month and year without writing redundant code. i have two columns in the dataframe where one has date values like 20001130  and another has date values like 2000-11-30 both represent different information.

Comment: You mean something like: `df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [20001129, '2000-11-30']})`? I updated the code accordingly.